# text-align justify and last line right-alignment not working for right to left language

Tags: android, html, css, text-alignment, justify

I'm trying to justify the text in webview android (for a right to left language) within the div tag, but the text just wont justify! Also last line is not right aligned! I have used below code, but not worked. http://jsfiddle.net/XkQrF/112/

```
    div {
    display:inline ;
    direction: rtl;
    text-align:justify;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    white-space:normal;
    text-align-last: right; -ms-text-align-last:right;
    }
```

Alse, I should note that I have used inline, because I want to place divs next to each other. thanks for any help.

Comment: Works fine without the `display :inline`... https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/4jw2kdoa/ So, how about `display: inline-block`?

Comment: Thank you @Mr Lister. But without  display :inline I cannot place divs next to each other. See the link: <http://jsfiddle.net/XkQrF/112/>

Comment: OK, see my answer. But what's with all the `left` and `top` properties? The divs are not positioned, so those properties do nothing.

Comment: @Mr Lister: I think you are right. But there is not any other way for placing divs next to each other without using inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that inline elements don't do `text-align` at all, nor `text-align-last`. This has nothing to do with the directionality of the text.

One solution would be to put all the divs in a container and give the alignment properties to the container.

```css
.container {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: right; -ms-text-align-last: right;
}

div {
  display: inline;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div style="left:118.67px;top:422.67px">
    <img alt='img' src='images\Java_GraphicFillImg_1.png' width="554.67px" height="1.33px" />
  </div>
  <div style="left:118.67px;top:502.67px">
    <img alt='img' src='images\Java_GraphicFillImg_2.png' width="554.67px" height="1.33px" />
  </div>
  <div style="left:489.33px;top:556.00px">
    <img alt='img' src='images\Java_GraphicFillImg_3.png' width="184.00px" height="1.33px" />
  </div>
  <div style="left:434.399900pt;top:116.555700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt; COLOR:RGB(255,0,0);font-family:Times New Roman">‫اﺻﻞ و ﻧﺴﺐ ﺟﺎوا‬</div>

  <div style="left:89.999900pt;top:159.839700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt;font-family:Times New Roman">‫ﺟﺎوا ﺑﻪ زﺑﺎن ++‪ C‬ﻧﺘﯿﺠﻪ ﻣﺴﺘﻘﯿﻢ زﺑﺎن ‪ C‬واﺑﺴﺘﻪ اﺳـﺖ . ﺑﺴـﯿﺎری از ﺧﺼـﻠﺘﻬﺎی ﺟـﺎوا ﺑﻄـﻮر ﻣﺴـﺘﻘﯿﻢ از اﯾـﻦ دو زﺑـﺎن‬</div>

  <div style="left:93.845900pt;top:179.939700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt;font-family:Tahoma">‫ﮔﺮﻓﺘﻪ ﺷﺪه اﺳﺖ . دﺳﺘﻮر زﺑﺎن ﺟﺎوا ﻣﻨﺘﺞ از دﺳﺘﻮر زﺑﺎن ‪ C‬اﺳﺖ . ﺑﺴـﯿﺎری از ﺟﻨﺒـﻪ ﻫـﺎی ‪ oop‬زﺑـﺎن ﺟـﺎوا از ++‪C‬‬</div>

  <div style="left:89.996300pt;top:204.863700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt;font-family:Times New Roman">‫ﺑﻌﺎرﯾﺖ ﮔﺮﻓﺘﻪ ﺷﺪه اﺳﺖ . در ﺣﻘﯿﻘﺖ ﺑﺴﯿﺎری از ﺧﺼﻠﺘﻬﺎی زﺑﺎن ﺟﺎوا از اﯾﻦ دو زﺑﺎن ﻣﺸﺘﻖ ﺷﺪه ﯾﺎ ﺑﺎ آﻧﻬﺎ ﻣـﺮﺗﺒﻂ اﺳـﺖ .‬</div>

  <div style="left:89.999900pt;top:224.843700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt;font-family:Times New Roman">‫ﻋﻼوه ﺑﺮ اﯾﻦ ، ﺗﻮﻟﯿﺪ ﺟﺎوا ﺑﻄﻮر ﻋﻤﯿﻘﯽ ﻣﺘﺎﺛﺮ از روال ﭘﺎﻻﯾﺶ و ﺗﻄﺒﯿﻘﯽ اﺳﺖ ﮐﻪ ﻃﯽ ﺳﻪ دﻫﻪ ﮔﺬﺷﺘﻪ ﺑﺮای زﺑﺎﻧﻬـﺎی ﺑﺮﻧﺎﻣـﻪ‬</div>

  <div style="left:93.959900pt;top:240.059700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt;font-family:Times New Roman">‫ﻧﻮﯾﺴﯽ ﻣﻮﺟﻮد ﭘﯿﺶ آﻣﺪه اﺳﺖ . ﺑﻬﻤﯿﻦ دﻻﯾﻞ ﺑﻬﺘﺮ اﺳﺖ ﺳﯿﺮ ﻣﺮاﺣﻞ و ﻧﯿﺮوﻫﺎﯾﯽ ﮐﻪ ﻣﻨﺠﺮ ﺑﻪ ﺗﻮﻟﺪ ﺟﺎوا ﺷﺪه را ﺑﺮرﺳـﯽ‬</div>

  <div style="left:89.999900pt;top:264.983700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt;font-family:Times New Roman">‫ﻧﻤﺎﯾﯿﻢ . ﻫﺮﻧﻮع اﺑﺘﮑﺎر و ﻓﮑﺮ ﺟﺪﯾﺪ در ﻃﺮاﺣﯽ زﺑﺎﻧﻬﺎ ﺑﺮاﺳﺎس ﻧﯿﺎز ﺑﻪ ﭘﺸﺖ ﺳﺮ ﻧﻬﺎدن ﯾﮏ ﻣﺸﮑﻞ اﺻﻠﯽ اﺳﺖ ﮐـﻪ زﺑﺎﻧﻬـﺎی‬</div>

  <div style="left:274.925900pt;top:280.199700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt;font-family:Tahoma">‫ﻗﺒﻠﯽ از ﺣﻞ آن ﻋﺎﺟﺰ ﻣﺎﻧﺪه اﻧﺪ . ﺟﺎوا ﻧﯿﺰ ﺑﻬﻤﯿﻦ ﺗﺮﺗﯿﺐ ﻣﺘﻮﻟﺪ ﺷﺪ .‬</div>

  <div style="left:89.999900pt;top:300.359700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt; COLOR:RGB(0,0,128);font-family:Times New Roman">‫ﺟﺎوا از ﻧﻈﺮ ﺳﺎﺧﺘﺎر ﺑﺴﯿﺎر ﺷﺒﯿﻪ زﺑﺎن ++‪ C/C‬و اﯾﻦ ﺑﻪ ﻫﯿﭻ وﺟﻪ ﺗﺼﺎدﻓﯽ ﻧﯿﺴﺖ ‪ c‬زﺑﺎﻧﯽ اﺳﺖ ﺳﺎﺧﺘﻪ ﯾﺎﻓﺘـﻪ و ++‪ c‬زﺑـﺎﻧﯽ‬</div>

  <div style="left:90.000000pt;top:320.459700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt; COLOR:RGB(0,0,128);font-family:Times New Roman">‫ﺷﯽ ﮔﺮا و ﻣﻬﻤﺘﺮ از ﻫﻤﻪ ﻗﺴﻤﺖ اﻋﻈﻢ ﺑﺮﻧﺎﻣﻪ ﻧﻮﯾﺴﺎن دﻧﯿﺎ از ++‪ C/C‬اﺳﺘﻔﺎده ﻣﯽ ﮐﻨﻨـﺪ. و از ﺳـﻮی دﯾﮕـﺮ اﯾـﻦ ﺣﺮﮐـﺖ ﺑـﻪ‬</div>

  <div style="left:327.420000pt;top:345.383700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt; COLOR:RGB(0,0,128);font-family:Times New Roman">‫ﻃﺮف ﺟﺎوا را ﺑﺮای اﯾﻦ ﻗﺒﯿﻞ اﻓﺮاد ﺳﺎده ﺧﻮاﻫﺪ ﮐﺮد.‬</div>

  <div style="left:90.000000pt;top:360.599700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt; COLOR:RGB(0,0,128);font-family:Times New Roman">‫ﺟﺎوا ﺑﺎ دور اﻧﺪاﺧﺘﻦ ﻧﺸﺎﻧﮕﺮﻫﺎ )‪(Pointers‬و ﺑﺮ دوش ﮐﺸﯿﺪن ﺑﺎر ﻣﺪﯾﺮﯾﺖ ﺣﺎﻓﻈـﻪ ﺑﺮﻧﺎﻣـﻪ ﻧﻮﯾﺴـﺎن ++‪ C/C‬را ﺑـﺮای‬</div>

  <div style="left:90.000000pt;top:380.759700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt; COLOR:RGB(0,0,128);font-family:Times New Roman">‫ﻫﻤﯿﺸﻪ از اﯾﻦ ﮐﺎﺑﻮس رﻫﺎﯾﯽ ﺑﺨﺸﯿﺪه اﺳﺖ ﺟﺎوا ﻫﻤﭽﻮن ++‪ C/C‬ﺑﻪ ﺑﺰرﮔﯽ و ﮐﻮﭼﮑﯽ ﺣـﺮوف ﺣﺴـﺎس اﺳـﺖ و ﺑﺮﻧﺎﻣـﻪ‬</div>

  <div style="left:367.980000pt;top:400.859700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt; COLOR:RGB(0,0,128);font-family:Times New Roman">‫ﻧﻮﺷﺘﻪ ﺷﺪه ﺑﺎﯾﺪ دارای ﻣﺘﺪ ‪ main‬ﺑﺎﺷﺪ.‬</div>

  <div style="left:406.080000pt;top:460.115700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt; COLOR:RGB(255,0,0);font-family:Times New Roman">‫زﻣﯿﻨﻪ ﻫﺎی ﭘﯿﺪاﯾﺶ ﺟﺎوا‬</div>

  <div style="left:90.000000pt;top:488.939700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt;font-family:Times New Roman">‫ﺗﺎرﯾﺨﭽﻪ زﺑﺎﻧﻬﺎی ﺑﺮﻧﺎﻣﻪ ﻧﻮﯾﺴﯽ ﺑﺸﺮح زﯾﺮ اﺳﺖ : زﺑﺎن ‪ B‬ﻣﻨﺠﺮ ﺑـﻪ ﻇﻬـﻮر زﺑـﺎن ‪ C‬و‪ C‬زﻣﯿﻨـﻪ ﭘﯿـﺪاﯾﺶ ++‪ C‬ﺷـﺪ و در‬</div>

  <div style="left:90.000000pt;top:509.039700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt;font-family:Times New Roman">‫ﻧﻬﺎﯾﺖ زﺑﺎن ﺟﺎوا ﻣﺘﻮﻟﺪ ﺷﺪ . درک زﺑﺎن ﺟﺎوا ﻣﺴﺘﻠﺰم : درک زﻣﯿﻨﻪ ﻫﺎی ﻻزم ﺑﺮای اﯾﺠﺎد ﺟﺎوا ، ﻧﯿﺮوﻫﺎﯾﯽ ﮐﻪ اﯾﻦ زﺑـﺎن‬</div>

  <div style="left:90.000000pt;top:529.199700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt;font-family:Times New Roman">‫را ﺷﮑﻞ داده اﻧﺪ و ﻣﺸﺨﺼﺎﺗﯽ اﺳﺖ ﮐﻪ اﯾﻦ زﺑﺎن از اﺳﻼف ﺧﻮد ﺑﻪ ارث ﺑﺮده اﺳﺖ . ﻧﻈﯿﺮ ﺳـﺎﯾﺮ زﺑﺎﻧﻬـﺎی ﺑﺮﻧﺎﻣـﻪ ﻧﻮﯾﺴـﯽ‬</div>

  <div style="left:90.000000pt;top:554.123700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt;font-family:Times New Roman">‫ﻣﻮﻓﻖ ، ﺟﺎوا ﻧﯿﺰ ﻋﻨﺎﺻﺮ ﺑﺎرث ﺑﺮده از اﺳﻼف ﺧﻮد را ﺑﺎ اﯾﺪه ﻫﺎی اﺑﺘﮑﺎری ﮐﻪ ﻧﺎﺷﯽ از ﻣﺤﯿﻂ ﻣﻨﺤﺼﺮ ﺑﻔﺮد اﯾﻦ زﺑـﺎن ﺑـﻮده‬</div>

  <div style="left:94.200000pt;top:569.339700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt;font-family:Times New Roman">‫درﻫﻢ آﻣﯿﺨﺘـﻪ اﺳـﺖ . ﻓﺼـﻮل ﺑﻌـﺪی ﺟﻨﺒـﻪ ﻫـﺎی ﻋﻤﻠـﯽ زﺑـﺎن ﺟـﺎوا ﺷـﺎﻣﻞ دﺳـﺘﻮر زﺑـﺎن )‪ (syntax‬و ﮐﺘﺎﺑﺨﺎﻧـﻪ ﻫـﺎ‬</div>

  <div style="left:90.000000pt;top:589.439700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt;font-family:Times New Roman">‫)‪(libraries‬و ﮐﺎرﺑﺮدﻫﺎی ﺟﺎوا را ﺗﻮﺻﯿﻒ ﻣﯽ ﮐﻨﺪ . ﻓﻌﻼ" ﭼﮕﻮﻧﮕﯽ و ﻋﻠﺖ ﻇﻬﻮر ﺟﺎوا و اﻫﻤﯿﺖ آن را ﺑﺮرﺳﯽ ﻣـﯽ‬</div>

  <div style="left:90.000000pt;top:609.599700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt;font-family:Times New Roman">‫ﮐﻨﯿﻢ . اﮔﺮ ﭼﻪ ﺟﺎوا ﺗﻔﮑﯿﮏ ﻧﺎﭘﺬﯾﺮی ﺑﺎ ﻣﺤﯿﻂ ﻫﺎی ﻫﻤﺰﻣﺎن اﯾﻨﺘﺮﻧﺖ ﭘﯿﻮﺳﺘﮕﯽ دارد ، اﻣﺎ ﺑﺨﺎﻃﺮ ﺑﺴﭙﺎرﯾﺪ ﮐﻪ ﺟﺎوا ﻗﺒـﻞ از‬</div>

  <div style="left:90.000000pt;top:634.523700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt;font-family:Times New Roman">‫ﻫﺮ ﭼﯿﺰ ﯾﮏ زﺑﺎن ﺑﺮﻧﺎﻣﻪ ﻧﻮﯾﺴﯽ اﺳﺖ . اﺑﺪاﻋﺎت و ﭘﯿﺸﺮﻓﺖ ﻫﺎ در زﺑﺎﻧﻬـﺎی ﺑﺮﻧﺎﻣـﻪ ﻧﻮﯾﺴـﯽ ﮐـﺎﻣﭙﯿﻮﺗﺮ ﺑـﺪو دﻟﯿـﻞ ﺑـﺮوز ﻣـﯽ‬</div>

  <div style="left:90.000000pt;top:649.739700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt;font-family:Times New Roman">‫ﮐﻨﻨﺪ : ﺗﻄﺎﺑﻖ ﺑﺎ ﺗﻐﯿﯿﺮات ﻣﺤﯿﻂ ﻫﺎ و ﮐﺎرﺑﺮدﻫﺎ . اﯾﺠﺎد ﭘﺎﻻﯾﺶ و ﭘﯿﺸـﺮﻓﺖ در ﻫﻨـﺮ ﺑﺮﻧﺎﻣـﻪ ﻧﻮﯾﺴـﯽ . ﻫﻤﺎﻧﻄﻮرﯾﮑـﻪ ﺑﻌـﺪا"‬</div>

  <div style="left:237.540000pt;top:674.603700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt;font-family:Times New Roman">‫ﻣﺸﺎﻫﺪه ﻣﯽ ﮐﻨﯿﺪ ، ﺗﻮﻟﺪ ﺟﺎوا از اﯾﻦ دو دﻟﯿﻞ ﺑﻄﻮر ﯾﮑﺴﺎن ﺑﻪ ارث ﮔﺮﻓﺘﻪ اﺳﺖ.‬</div>

  <div style="left:90.000000pt;top:694.583700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt;font-family:Times New Roman">‫ﺟﺎوا ﻫﻢ ﻣﺎﻧﻨﺪ اﮐﺜﺮ اﺧﺘﺮاﻋﺎت ﻣﻬﻢ ﺣﺎﺻﻞ ﺗﻼش ﮔﺮوﻫﯽ داﻧﺸﻤﻨﺪ ﭘﯿﺸﺘﺎز اﺳﺖ . ﻣﺪﯾﺮان ﺳﺎن ﺑﻪ اﯾﻦ ﻓﮑﺮ اﻓﺘﺎدﻧﺪ ﮐﻪ ﮐـﺎری‬</div>

  <div style="left:90.000000pt;top:709.859700pt;FONT-SIZE:12.000000pt;font-family:Times New Roman">‫ﮐﻨﻨﺪ ﮐﻪ ﺳﯿﺴﺘﻢ ﻣﺰﺑﻮر ﺑﺘﻮاﻧﺪ ﺑﻪ ﺳﯿﺴﺘﻢ ﺳﺨﺖ اﻓﺰاری ﻣﺨﺘﻠﻒ ﻣﻨﺘﻘﻞ ﺷﻮد . ﺑﺮای اﯾﻦ ﻣﻨﻈﻮر اﺑﺘﺪا از ﮐﺎﻣﭙﺎﯾﻠﺮ ++‪ c‬اﺳﺘﻔﺎده‬</div>

</section>
```

By the way, why are you using divs for inline pieces of text? I see no reason to not use spans there. Divs are meant to be blocks! (Sorry, pet peeve of mine.)

Comment: Thank you @Mr Lister. It seems that everything is OKKKK!!!! Using spans is really better. My html code is output of a converter app which needs to be modified.